# Using Carrierwave, how can I make sure the remote url is valid picture before trying to save it to the record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, carrierwave

I was attempting to save my picture files in the following manner in my ActiveJob, but a lot of my records were showing up as invalid. After looking into why, it appears the remote url isn't finding a valid picture and is returning a 404 error message.  How can I change my current setup to (1) attempt to get the picture, (2) if it's an invalid link then ignore it and still save the record -- just without the picture?

My current setup...

```
if self.headshot_url.present?
   player_record.remote_headshot_image_url = self.headshot_url
   if !player_record.valid?
     player_record.remote_headshot_image_url = nil
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use [FastImage](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage) gem to fast find image size and type. You can too use to check image is valid or not.

```
FastImage.type('https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage') 
=> nil

FastImage.type('https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png')
 => :png
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make `HEAD` http-request to the picture url, and check response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a [stdlib HTTP library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) that you can use:

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/some_path?query=string')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  response = http.head('/')
  if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
    puts "Yay"
  else
    puts "Oh noes"
  end
end
```

To create a validation which checks if URL is valid you would do:

```
require 'net/http'
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  validates :headshot_url_must_be_valid, if: -> { headshot_url.present? }

  def headshot_url_must_be_valid
    uri = URI(headshot_url)
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
     response = http.head('/')
     unless response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
       # This is how you would normally do validation
       # errors.add(:headshot_url, "is invalid. #{res.code} - #{res.msg}")
       self[:headshot_url] = nil
     end
    end
  end
end
```